# Can I use unrelated types as constraints in generic classes?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to create a generic class where T parameter can be any instance from the set of other types.
So this code compiles fine:

```cs
public interface TestA { }
public interface TestB { }
public class Test<T> where T : TestA, TestB
{

}
```

However, when I try to use it like this

```cs
var a = new Test<TestA>();
var b = new Test<TestB>();
```

I get two compile errors:

> Error 1   The type 'TestA' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'Test'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'TestA' to 'TestB'.
>
> Error 2   The type 'TestB' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'Test'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'TestB' to 'TestA'.

I am confused as to why this doesn't work. How can I workaround this? Ideally, I'd like TestA and TestB classes to have no relation (eg. no inheritance between them).

Comment: You're constraining the parameter to inherit **both** interfaces.  Constraining to inherit either would be useless.

Answer (score 3):

The type must follow all contraints defined on the generic type (AND, not OR).

If you want to allow both TestA or TestB, you should define a base interface :

```
public interface TestBase { }
public interface TestA : TestBase { }
public interface TestB : TestBase { }
public class Test<T> where T : TestBase
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you specified that the class must implement both interfaces. So you must give it a class that implements both interfaces, not just A or B

```
public class LikeThis : TestA, TestB
{

  // have both A and B's properties, methods, etc.
}

var a = new Test<LikeThis>();
```

The other option is to make both TestA and TestB inherit from a base interface

```
public interface IBaseInterface  { }
public interface IInterfaceA { }
public interface IInterfaceB { }

public class Test<T> where T : IBaseInterface
{

}

var a = new Test<IBaseInterface>();
```

But it is hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish here. The Test class could possibly hold a reference to IBaseInterface as a property, but it will not know if it is InterfaceA or InterfaceB.

Maybe if you tell us what you are trying to accomplish we can suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints on the type parameter are conjunctive (AND), so any type used there must implement both interfaces.

One way, as already mentioned, is to create a super-interface to both interfaces and constrain your type parameter to that (note that I added the usual interface prefix `I`):

```
public interface IBase { }
public interface ITestA : TestBase { }
public interface ITestB : TestBase { }
public class Test<T> where T : IBase {
}
```

That has the disadvantage that it's not just implementers of `ITestA` or `ITestB` that can be used as type parameters in `Test<T>`, but any other type that implements `IBase`.

Another option is to provide a super class that cannot be inherited from outside your assembly and create two sub-classes from it, one for each desired interface type:

```
public interface ITestA { }
public interface ITestB { }
public abstract class Test<T> {
    internal Test() { }
}
public class Test1<T> : Test<T> where T : ITestA { }
public class Test2<T> : Test<T> where T : ITestB { }
```

Now the `Test<T>` superclass cannot be inherited from outside your assembly (it has an `internal` constructor). Your classes (`Test1<T>` and `Test2<T>`) just use the logic of the superclass and each works with one of the desired interfaces as a constraint. Client code would have to choose which one to use based on the interface constraint they'd like to use.

Also, if you have common code in your interfaces that you'd like to use inside `Test<T>`, you should extract that to a super-interface and have your super-class be constrained by it, resulting in a hybrid of both approaches:

```
public interface IBase { }
public interface ITestA : IBase { }
public interface ITestB : IBase { }
public abstract class Test<T> where T : IBase {
    internal Test() { }
}
public class Test1<T> : Test<T> where T : ITestA { }
public class Test2<T> : Test<T> where T : ITestB { }
```